# How do I get a playlist to resize itself based upon screen size?

Tags: html

The playlist is too big for my monitor so it has scroll bars on the bottom and side.

Here is the source code:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <iframe 
            allowfullscreen="true" 
            allowtransparency="true" 
            class="wistia_playlist" 
            frameborder="0" 
            height="720" 
            width="1280"
            name="wistia_playlist"
            style="border:5px"
            scrolling="no"
            src="example link"
        ></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried some examples from the internet but they haven't worked so far. If it makes any difference I am doing this in a DNN HTML module for a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
iframe {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
<div>
    <p>
        <iframe 
            allowfullscreen="true" 
            allowtransparency="true" 
            class="wistia_playlist" 
            frameborder="0" 
            height="720" 
            width="1280"
            name="wistia_playlist"
            style="border:5px"
            scrolling="no"
            src="http://example.com"
        ></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
```

Allow resize using css!! `resize:both;`

Comment: Thanks! It even allows the user to re-size the video manually if they so choose.